# Why am I getting an activetab permission error?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm making one of those Chrome extensions that overrides new tab content. I pieced together what I learned and created this manifest.json file:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "myTest",
    "description": "Stuff in a new chrome tab.",
    "version": "1",
    "author": "DD",

    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Testing"
    },

    "chrome_url_overrides": {
        "newtab": "newtab.html"
    },

    "permissions": ["activetab"]
}
```

In the developer console, it generates an error:

```
permission "activetab" is unknown or url pattern is malformed
```

It actually works great, so I'm wondering if this is more of a caution than an error and if it would be rejected when publishing?

Comment: It's case-sensitive: `activeTab`

Comment: Wow. I must be tired.